# XMLDiff - get only the differences between two xml

Tags: c#, xmldiff

Is there any option to get only the differences between two xml using XMLDiff and XMLDiffView.

Also is there any possibility to get the line number of the modification in the xml

Take a look on below sample.

XML1

```
<Products>
<Product level="1" >
    <ProductId>1001</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName1</Name>
    <ProductType>Groceries</ProductType>
    <Stock type="box">100</Stock>
    <Comment />
</Product>
<Product>
    <ProductId>1003</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName3</Name>
    <ProductType>Garments</ProductType>
    <Stock type="packet">50</Stock>
    <Comment>Information about the product</Comment>
</Product>
```

Xml2

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <ProductId>1003</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName3</Name>
    <ProductType>Garments</ProductType>
    <Stock type="box">50</Stock>        
</Product>
<Product>
    <ProductId>1004</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName4</Name>
    <ProductType>SportsEquipment</ProductType>
    <Stock>100</Stock>
    <Comment />
</Product>
<Product level="1" >
    <ProductId>1001</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName1</Name>
    <ProductType>Groceries</ProductType>
    <Stock type="box">80</Stock>
    <Comment />
</Product>
```

Result:

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <Stock type="box">50</Stock>
    <Stock>80</Stock>       
</Product>
<Product>
    <Comment>Information about the product</Comment> //Removed - Need to specify
</Product>
<Product>
    <ProductId>1004</ProductId>
    <Name>ProductName4</Name>
    <ProductType>SportsEquipment</ProductType>
    <Stock>100</Stock>
    <Comment />
</Product>
```

Is there any settings in XMLDiffView to get the above result as output. I am comparing large amount of xml so showing all content will look like mess.